# what is difference between "on" and "about"?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, meaning-in-context, prepositions, writing

which preposition is more suitable to use and why ?

1-To find more information **about** the available scholarship.

2-To find more information **on** the available scholarship.

Comment: Is there only one scholarship avalable?

Comment: I think that there's a slight difference between British and American practice in this case. As far as I know both prepositions are used in both dialects but BrEng tends to favour 'about' while AnEng tends to favour 'on'. I don't think that there's any real difference in meaning between 'information about' and ''information on' in either dialect, it's mainly a matter of personal preference. I'm British so I tend to say 'information about'.

Comment: It should be noted that, even though this question is indeed a duplicate, the question that it is a duplicate of has not received an answer that can be regarded as definite. (This is another example of the inaptness of various automatically generated notices on this site: one may agree that something is a duplicate and still respond 'no' to 'Does this answer your question?')

Comment: A similar question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229189/this-is-a-novel-about-on-integrity)

Answer (score 0):

The answer below is as concise, relevant, and informative an answer than any I could give:

[Thursagen's answer on "What is the difference between “information on”, “information of”, “information about”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32838/what-is-the-difference-between-information-on-information-of-information#:%7E:text=%22information%20of%20something%22%20used%20in,about%20something%22%20in%20this%20case.)

In this light, I would argue that  "information on" [the available scholarship] would be more suitable since the modifier *more* implies the need of information more in-depth than what is currently available.

Comment: The answer you link to seems to be one person's opinion.

Answer (score -2):

Both mean pretty much the same.

In some tricky cases, depending on what the prepositional phrase is modifying in the reader's view, the perceived meaning of the statement changes.

For example, take the famous Groucho Marx joke:

> One morning I shot an elephant in my pajamas.

Here the prepositional phrase can be thought of both as an adverb or an adjective. The former makes no sense, but the latter does.

Comment: Apart from the very short first sentence, it is not exactly clear how these remarks are related to the question.

Comment: That first sentence answers the question. The rest is just to show the special cases as both on and about are prepositions, so I went a bit out of scope to answer. I didn't have 50 reputation, so I couldn't comment and had to answer.